# auto-refreshing MySQL query on Linux commandline

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line

I would like to see a auto refreshing MySQL query result in my linux console.

something like this:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
clear
//some special way of executing 'select id from updates order by id desc limit 1'
sleep 1
done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
watch -n 1 "mysql -e 'select id from updates order by id desc limit 1' your_db"
```

Comment: oh it is the parameter -e. how did I miss that!

Comment: @Alasdair: I fixed the quoting. (You or schworak could have done the same).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon it while trying to figure out the same thing and the answer is not quite right. MySQL and Watch don't seem to play nice together unless you wrap the entire mysql command in double quotes like this...

```
watch -n 1 "mysql -e 'select id from updates order by your_db.id desc limit 1'"
```

Without the double quotes, I kept getting the help info rather than the results from my select. I had to have the user name and password parms to make my query work which isn't recommended. Probably isn

Answer (score 1):

An extremely minor addition to the accepted answer is that, for ease of editing, I like to put the query first as below:

```bash
Q='select * from users' && watch -n 1 "mysql -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME -e '$Q'"
```